# Объединение двух таблиц MySQL phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Существуют две таблицы: main и descr

main содержит столбцы name, surname, date и пустой столбец descr,
таблица descr в свою очередь содержит только заполненный столбец descr,
такой вопрос, как объединить эти две таблицы в одну, а точнее перенести столбец из descr в main.

Comment: В описанных условиях - никак. Невозможно определить, к какой строке main какая строка descr относится.

Comment: @Akina хорошо, а если во второй таблице сделать идентичные столбцы как в первой таблице, то будет ли возможно?

Comment: *если во второй таблице сделать идентичные столбцы как в первой таблице* Если в первой таблице существует хотя бы один уникальный индекс - во второй таблице должны существовать поля, позволяющие построить такой же индекс, и тоже уникальный. И да - надо не просто "сделать идентичные столбцы", в них ещё и данные должны быть.